# How can I know whether a process is waiting for user input?

Tags: c#, process

I am simulating a console window in my project. I use the `Process` class to run a console application, and I use a `TextBox` for the user to interact with the console application. I wish to make the `TextBox` enabled only when the process is waiting for user input.

However I could find no way to do that. Here is a similar question:
[Is my process waiting for input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704791/is-my-process-waiting-for-input) But the solution to that question does not work for me. I have tried

```
foreach (ProcessThread thread in process.Threads)
    if (thread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Wait)
    {
        // see what thread.WaitReason is
    }
```

But `thread.WaitReason` always give `ThreadWaitReason.Executive`, both when the process is busy and when it is waiting for input.

Now my alternative solution is to parse the output, since the console application prints a string of a certain pattern every time it needs an input. But that's not a good solution, since there might be mistakes, and it may fail with other console applications, if the output is very difficult to parse, or not parsable at all.

So, is there a way to detect whether the process is waiting for input?

Comment: Why not just run a normal console window?

Comment: There just isn't any point in helping.  The user can already tell when it is ready.  And if you send input and the app isn't ready then it just gets buffered.  Type-ahead, nice feature.

Comment: I parse and highlight the output with different colors, and I handle the event when the user clicks the lines of the output. It will be difficult to implement if I use just a console window.

Comment: @Hans Passant It looks weird when you enter a string and the application gives some output and your input moves along with it. Of course it is okay but I just want to make it more like a real console window, where input is not displayed until the application pauses and waits for input.

Comment: FWIW, At a lower level (kernel thread scheduler) windows knows if a thread is waiting on an I/O, but I haven't ever seen a high level API which can provide this information. I have a feeling that the thread scheduler does not retain any information about why a thread was put into wait-state, other than marking them `alertable` or not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is my process waiting for input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704791/is-my-process-waiting-for-input)